# Konjunktiv I statt II in einer Traumbeschreibung von Kästner

Tags: subjunctive

Falls ich es richtig verstehe, wird der [Konjunktiv I](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktiv#Konjunktiv_I) meist für die indirekte Rede verwendet, und daneben für die Wunschform.  In Erich Kästners *Der Gang für die Hunde* steht am Anfang des sechzehntes Kapitel:

> Fabian sah das Alles, als führen nur seine Augen und Ohren durch Berlin, und er selber sei weit, weit weg.

Hier wird offenbar die Konjunktiv I verwendet, aber warum?  Es ist keine indirekte Rede (niemand redet) und keine Wunschform.  Es ist eher Irrealis, aber das Irrealis wird wohl mit Konjunktiv II gebildet.  Dann wäre dieser Satz anders gewesen: *er selber wäre*, statt *er selber sei* (für *führen* ist die Form schon gleich zwischen Konjunktiv I und II).  Warum ist es hier *er sei weit weg* und nicht *er wäre weit weg*?

Answer (score 6):

Das [Verb fahren](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:fahren) ist hochgradig unregelmäßig und daher liegt hier wohl ein Missverständnis vor. Es handelt sich in dem oben genannten Fall tatsächlich um Konjunktiv II ("führen") und nicht um Konjunktiv I ("fahren").

Anders verhält es sich natürlich mit dem zweiten Teil. 
"Er selber sei weit, weit weg" ist Konjunktiv I, allerdings kann es sich hier auch wieder um die Wunschform handeln.

EDIT: 
Ich möchte noch zusätzlich auf den ersten Kommentar (sgf) hinweisen: Es gibt natürlich den Konjunktiv I "sie führen" vom Verb "führen", welcher identisch ist mit dem Indikativ. Allerdings handelt es sich in der Frage um das Verb "fahren" und nicht "führen.

Comment: Um klar zu machen, was hier passiert: Es gibt tatsächlich einen Konjunktiv I von führen "sie führen", aber der würde nie verwendet werden, weil er mit dem Indikative ident ist. "Sie führen" ist Konjunktiv II von "fahren", und wird (ganz regelmäßig) mit Umlaut vom Präteritum abegleitet: "Sie fuhren" (Präteritum) -> "Sie führen" (Konjunktiv II)

Comment: Meine Frage bezieht sich meist auf das zweite Teil *Er selber sei weit, weit weg*.  Weshalb ist es hier denn Wunschform?  Wer wünscht?

Comment: Ich kenne den Kontext nicht, aber es ist zumindest möglich, dass Fabian sich wünscht, weit weg zu sein.

Comment: Ich weise darauf hin: Wenn eine Verbform im Konjunktiv 1 dieselbe ist wie im Indikativ, dann wird der Konjunktiv 2 verwendet. (Beispiel: "Ich sagte, ich haette Geld," statt "Ich sagte, ich habe Geld).
Im Textbeispiel ist also "fuehren" auch Konjunktiv 1, ausgedrueckt mit der Form des Konjunktiv 2 (Bzw. man kann es so auslegen, denn dann stimmen beide Verben im Satz, fuehren und sei, ueberein).